# Python 2.x - QueryPerformanceCounter() on Windows

Tags: python, windows, time, clock, performancecounter

I would like to program my own clock object using Python. I'd like it to be very, very accurate. I read that on Windows, I could use QueryPerformanceCounter(). But how? I don't know any C; only Python 2.x.

Can someone give me a hint on how to make use of this in Python to make an accurate clock on Win?

Comment: Where is `QueryPerformanceCounter()`? Windows API?

Comment: yes - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you. I'm doing some testing now, I'm sure I have a solution in a few minustes. Keep looking :)

Comment: that is very kind, thanks !

Comment: Ok, I've figured something out now. What I not exactly understand is the usage of the function, it returns (written in the docs) only zero on failure and non zero on success. Do you know anything on that?

Comment: there's a further link on the site: "Acquiring high-resolution time stamps", butI don't get it - it's too technical for me. But there should be a few examples there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx#examples_for_acquiring_time_stamps

Comment: I see :) I'll port this to Python, just wait...

Comment: It's a bit tricky at all. I try to use the `ctypes` module, which gave me access to the function. Now I'm stuck with the type conversion between Python and C++, but I'll try. If you want so, I can post the code I made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've ported the [C++ example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx#examples_for_acquiring_time_stamps) you've given to Python using the `ctypes` module:

**C++**

```
LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;

QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency); 
QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);

// Activity to be timed

QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;

ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000;
ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
```

**Python**

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
import time

kernel32             = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

starting_time        = ctypes.wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER()
ending_time          = ctypes.wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER()
elapsed_microseconds = ctypes.wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER()
frequency            = ctypes.wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER()

kernel32.QueryPerformanceFrequency(ctypes.byref(frequency)) 
kernel32.QueryPerformanceCounter(ctypes.byref(starting_time))

# Activity to be timed, e.g.
time.sleep(2)

kernel32.QueryPerformanceCounter(ctypes.byref(ending_time))

elapsed_microseconds = ending_time.value - starting_time.value
elapsed_microseconds *= 1000000
elapsed_microseconds /= frequency.value

print(elapsed_microseconds)
```

I really appreciate the useful hints of **@eryksun**!

The code above should print something near to `2000000` (e.g. `2000248.7442040185`, the value may be different from time to time). You may also use the `round()` or `int()` function to get rid of the decimals.

As @eryksun has commented you can also use [`time.clock()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock), which is implemented in C and also uses `QueryPerformanceCounter()`.

Example doing exactly the same as the one using `ctypes`:

```
import time
starting_time = time.clock()

# Activity to be timed, e.g.
time.sleep(2)

ending_time = time.clock()

elapsed_microseconds = ending_time - starting_time
elapsed_microseconds *= 1000000

print(elapsed_microseconds)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for your efforts, but I can't make it work without learning C I guess. I don't know about C types so I can't fix the workaround you have provided

Comment: Hmm ok. If you are around on SO sometimes, I can comment to you if I have more ideas.

Comment: I just found out that these c_longlong_Array_1 objects are iterable and obj[0] is the time value I think: Try "ElapsedMicroseconds = EndingTime[0] - StartingTime[0]"

Comment: On Windows, [`time.clock`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) is [implemented](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.12/Modules/timemodule.c#l162) via [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904) and [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905).

Comment: Avoid `windll`. Some other ctypes-based library might be used in the same script, but with definitions of `restype`, `argtypes`, and `errcheck` that break your code. Instead use `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)`. Set the `errcheck` attribute (see the docs) on functions that support the Windows last error value, which you can get safely via `ctypes.get_last_error()` and get an exception via `ctypes.WinError(code)`. Use `ctypes.wintypes` for Windows data types, e.g `st = wintypes.LARGE_INTEGER();` `kernel32.QueryPerformanceCounter(ctypes.byref(st))`.

Comment: @eryksun - Thank you for the information! I am fairly new to `ctypes` and still learning that stuff. The OP may agree with using `time.clock`. I'll edit my answer :)

Comment: @DonPolettone - Updated my answer, I hope this is what you need! If so, please mark my answer as accepted!

Comment: Hi again eryksun & linusg. Thanks a lot for these useful inputs! I got my clock working now and it's not too bad, but now another issue popped up.. but that's worth a new question ;-) THX

Comment: posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487114/python-2-x-sleep-call-at-microsecond-level-on-windows