# Python 2.x - sleep call at millisecond level on Windows

Tags: python, windows, time, sleep, clock

I was given some very good hints in this forum about how to code a clock object in Python 2. I've got some code working now. It's a clock that 'ticks' at 60 FPS:

```
import sys
import time

class Clock(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.init_os()
        self.fps = 60.0
        self._tick = 1.0 / self.fps
        print "TICK", self._tick
        self.check_min_sleep()
        self.t = self.timestamp()

    def init_os(self):

        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.timestamp = time.clock
            self.wait = time.sleep

    def timeit(self, f, args):

        t1 = self.timestamp()
        f(*args)
        t2 = self.timestamp()
        return t2 - t1

    def check_min_sleep(self):
        """checks the min sleep time on the system"""

        runs =  1000
        times = [self.timeit(self.wait, (0.001, )) for n in xrange(runs)]
        average = sum(times) / runs
        print "average min sleep time:", round(average, 6)
        sort = sorted(times)
        print "fastest, slowest", sort[0], sort[-1]

    def tick(self):

        next_tick = self.t + self._tick
        t = self.timestamp()
        while t < next_tick:
            t = self.timestamp()
        self.t = t

if __name__ == "__main__":
    clock = Clock()
```

The clock does not do too bad, but in order to avoid a busy loop I'd like Windows to sleep less than the usual about 15 milliseconds. On my system (64-bit Windows 10), it returns me an average of about 15 / 16 msecs when starting the clock if Python is the only application that's running. That's way too long for a min sleep to avoid a busy loop.

Does anybody know how I can get Windows to sleep less than that value?

Comment: Seriously? You want to sleep for less than 0.015 *microseconds*? As in 15 nanoseconds? 60 FPS is 60 frames per *second*, not frames per microsecond.

Comment: sorry fixed that...

Comment: You can lower it to the minimum allowed timer period, which is probably about 1 ms (queried via `winmm!timeGetDevCaps`). Is that good enough?

Comment: That sounds very good, but how can I use it with Python 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can temporarily lower the timer period to the `wPeriodMin` value returned by [`timeGetDevCaps`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757627). The following defines a `timer_resolution` context manager that calls the [`timeBeginPeriod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757624) and [`timeEndPeriod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757626) functions.

```
import timeit
import contextlib
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

winmm = ctypes.WinDLL('winmm')

class TIMECAPS(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('wPeriodMin', wintypes.UINT),
                ('wPeriodMax', wintypes.UINT))

def _check_time_err(err, func, args):
    if err:
        raise WindowsError('%s error %d' % (func.__name__, err))
    return args

winmm.timeGetDevCaps.errcheck = _check_time_err
winmm.timeBeginPeriod.errcheck = _check_time_err
winmm.timeEndPeriod.errcheck = _check_time_err

@contextlib.contextmanager
def timer_resolution(msecs=0):
    caps = TIMECAPS()
    winmm.timeGetDevCaps(ctypes.byref(caps), ctypes.sizeof(caps))
    msecs = min(max(msecs, caps.wPeriodMin), caps.wPeriodMax)
    winmm.timeBeginPeriod(msecs)
    yield
    winmm.timeEndPeriod(msecs)

def min_sleep():
    setup = 'import time'
    stmt = 'time.sleep(0.001)'
    return timeit.timeit(stmt, setup, number=1000)
```

### Example

```
>>> min_sleep()
15.6137827

>>> with timer_resolution(msecs=1): min_sleep()
...
1.2827173000000016
```

The original timer resolution is restored after the `with` block:

```
>>> min_sleep()
15.6229814
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to understand: 'winmm.timeBeginPeriod(msecs)' switches the min sleep and 'winmm.timeEndPeriod(msecs)' resets it again, is that right?

Comment: Yes, the two calls have to be matched. I used a context manager to emphasize that you should restore the original timer period as soon as possible. As the docs explain, this affects thread scheduling globally and can degrade system performance and power management.

Comment: but it would be safe to tick the clock with high resolution and switch back right after?

Comment: You might want the `Clock` class to be a context manager, and document that entering it on Windows sets the system timer period to its minimum value to avoid having to busy loop over the entire period. You'll still need to busy loop a bit to get the accuracy of `time.clock`.

Comment: OK, but if I use this in a game or emulator, how can I assure that the timer period is reset whenever the program quits?

Comment: In your `main` function you would execute the game in the context of something like `with Clock() as clk`. That's assuming the `Clock` class implements the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods of the context manager protocol. On entering it sets the system timer to the minimum value. On exit it restores the original timer period.

Comment: Is a context manager the only solution? I am not familiar with the 'with' statement and it's kinda creepy :-/

Comment: Managing resources with context managers is fundamental to Python programming. But if you really insist on another way to ensure the timer period is restored at exit, you can register an [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) function. Also, it's not documented, but the default timer period gets restored when your program exits -- even when killed forcefully via `TerminateProcess`.