# Why won't delay change the speed of the clicking on my auto clicker?

Tags: python, pynput

Hello Stack Overflow users, I am wondering how to fix my **Python** Auto Clicker. This is **Python 3.9.7** and I am using the program **Visual Studio Code** from [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and when I change my `delay` variable it stays clicking at the same speed. I am using **pynput** importing to check if key is pressed and to get the mouse with `pynput.keyboard` and `pynput.mouse` I also import the mouse with `from pynput import mouse`. Is their anyway to make my own waiting script kinda like `time.sleep(float)` well anyways lets get to the point. Here is the code:

```py
###################
## Python Script Made by: Ryans World
## Python Script Based off of: PyTutorials on YouTube
## Python Version: 3.9.7
## Recommended Versions: 3.10 or 3.9.7
###################
    
# Imports
    
import threading
import time
from pynput import mouse
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

# Variables

delay = 0.01
button = Button.left

# Functions

class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super().__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True
    
    # Run the script;returns True
    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True
    
    # Stop the script;returns False
    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False
    
    # Exit the program;breaks the script
    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False
    
    # Runs the AutoClicking
    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)

# Thread & Mouse

mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()

# Checks if USER pressed key to run program
def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.alt_l:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == Key.esc:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop() # Shuts down program completely

# Joins the Program with the 'on_press' function
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: does it work with a much greater delay? (like 5s)

Comment: I do not know I will test that right now!

Comment: Yes it does work with a higher number! ti7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why time.sleep() is so slow in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40594587/why-time-sleep-is-so-slow-in-windows)

Comment: Sadly no @ti7 It did not work.

Comment: you've already said it worked, just depends on the values. What values are you using for `delay` and how do you know it is the same? Have you timed how long the `mouse.click` function takes?

Comment: You cannot sleep for a time shorter than the computer's scheduler interval.  It doesn't even check the timer list until then  The system doesn't create a new interrupt for every timer.  On Windows, that minimum is about 16ms.  On Linux, it's about 10ms.

Comment: So it is impossible for me to do lower than 16ms?